# mysql workbenk showing stange character on query execution

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, charset

Data retrieved from a query in mysql workbench are not readble, but when I copy and paste the data in editor the results are readble. Please advise if there is any setting to change them. Thanks! [image]

Answer (score 0):

if you using Ubuntu OS. maybe trouble with font problem.

can you change other font in Preferences -> Fonts ?